# PyInstaller error loading Python DLL when running executable on another machine

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cross-platform

I'm trying to run a pyinstaller-built executable on another machine. The error I see is `Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI70722\python39.dll`

I built the program like this, I also added `-F` to make sure the executable is standalone:

`py -m PyInstaller script.py -F`

I tried adding `--add-binary` and `--add-data` options with the path to `python39.dll`, but that didn't help.

The program is built on *Windows 10 x64*, the machine I'm trying to run the program on is *Windows 7 x64*. Even with such a difference and the fact that *Python 3.9* is not for Windows 7, I really doubt this is the reason, otherwise I would expect another error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this error really that bad? Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's solution that worked for me:

1. Install a Windows7-compatible version of python3. I did this from the Windows Store, which made it accessible in my command line as "python3."
2. Set up a virtual environment with your downgraded version of python. On command line, that's

   *...>* python3 -m venv my_env
3. In command line, navigate to your newly created environment directory, and use pip to re-install pyinstaller in your new environment:

   *...>* cd my_env

   *...\my_env>* pip install pyinstaller
4. From command line in my_env, use pyinstaller to compile your code. You should probably move script.py into your my_env directory.

   *...\my_env>* pyinstaller script.py -F

I was able to copy the standalone script created in \my_env onto a Windows 7 machine and run it successfully. Hope this helps!

Comment: in another machine too